# Using a PHP variable inside JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, session, session-variables

I'm pretty new, so go easy. I am using a session in PHP with a few variables. I want to concatenate two strings together from my PHP session when the clicks a button. I am using JavaScript onclick to try and achieve this.

I am having trouble getting my JavaScript to accept my PHP variables. Does anybody have any suggestions?

PHP:

```
$_SESSION['user1'] = $_POST['user'];
$_SESSION['string3'] = $_POST['string1'];
$_SESSION['string4'] = $_POST['string2'];

echo $_SESSION['user1'];
echo $_SESSION['string3'];
echo $_SESSION['string4'];

if(isset($_SESSION['user1'])) {
    echo 'Welcome, '.$_SESSION['user1'].". Lets concatenate ".$_SESSION['string3']." and ".$_SESSION['string4'];

} else {
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=">";
}


<button onclick="xy()">Try it</button>
<p id="answer"></p>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function xy() {
    var x = "<?php $_SESSION['string3']; ?>";
    var y = "<?php $_SESSION['string4']; ?>";
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = x + y;
}
</script>
```

Comment: what file is the js in ?

Comment: what does the source say of your php page?

Comment: These are both in the same .php file

Comment: `echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=">";` has an unescaped quote.

Comment: yes, the script is below the php

Comment: I was only trying to hide the URL dave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to echo the PHP variable there because otherwise they output nothing and the JS variable ends up empty:

```
var x = "<?php echo $_SESSION['string3']; ?>";
var y = "<?php echo $_SESSION['string4']; ?>";
```

So for example, if `$_SESSION['string3']` is "abc", PHP will echo the value inside the JS and you'll get this:

```
var x = "abc";
```

instead of:

```
var x = ""; // no output from PHP when there's no echo
```

---

To simplify things, here is your whole function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function xy() {
    var x = "<?php echo $_SESSION['string3']; ?>";
    var y = "<?php echo $_SESSION['string4']; ?>";
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = x + y;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Ah, sadly I was too slow to post a full answer, so I'll extend this one. There's a shorthand for equivalent behavior: `<?= $_SESSION['string3']; ?>`

Comment: @boxmein I wrote it, and then decided to remove it because OP seems new to all this and didn't want to confuse him further. But yes, it's worth mentioning, thank you. :)

Comment: Where should I echo the PHP variable inside the JS function xy()?

Comment: No, no, just once for x and once for y and that's it... From there, JS 'knows' the new values and you don't need to echo them from PHP again. I've updated my answer to show you the whole function.

Comment: @Shomz I updated the JS code as shown above. Nothing happens when I click the button. Am I missing something else?

Comment: Hm, I assume you closed the PHP tag before the button and the answer HTML code starts? Here's something you can do for debugging, set a default answer (like this: `<p id="answer">SOMETHING HERE</p>`) and see what happens when you click the button. If the answer changes to nothing/empty string, it means your PHP session variables are not set. If nothing happens, JS is wrong someplace and it might be time to learn to use the console to debug the code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it should be something like this?

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n";
echo "function xy() {\n";
echo "var x = ".$_SESSION['string3']."\";\n";
echo "var y = ".$_SESSION['string4']."\";\n";
echo "document.getElementById(\"answer\").innerHTML = x + y;\n}";
echo "</script>";
```

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: @Shomz Just in case if the page was fully generated by PHP.